# How I can pass a value to a controller using a component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass a value to my controller trough my component but im still getting this undefined message. Am I missing something?

**myhtml.html**

```
<my-component item="value1"></my-component>
<my-component item="value2"></my-component>
<my-component item="value3"></my-component>
```

**mycomponent.js**

```
angular
    .module('mycomponent.component', [
        'mycomponent.controller'
    ])
    .component('myComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'components/mycomp/mycomp.component.html',
        controller: 'ComponentController',
        controllerAs: 'componentVM',
        replace: true,
        bindings: {
            item: '='
        }
    });
```

**mycontroller.js**

```
angular
    .module('mycomponent.controller', [])
    .controller('ComponentController', ComponentController);

    ComponentController.$inject = [];

    function ComponentController() {
        var vm = this;
        console.log('item value> ' + vm.item); // This is got undefined :(
    }
```

Comment: You need to put the `console.log()` (or anything using vm.item, for that matter) inside the `this.$onInit = function () {  /* bound properties available here */ }`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments by @mhodges put all your logic 
inside the `$onInit` hook. 
`$onInit` is triggered as part of the component life cycle when all your bindings are initialized.

```
var self = this;
self.$onInit = function(){
  console.log('item value> ' + self.item);
}
```

Back to your code, if `value1` is a primitive type you should be using a single way binding `@` (primitive type cannot use a two way binding as they aren't references)

```
bindings: {
  item: '@'
}

<my-component item="value1"></my-component>
```

In a scenario where `item` is an object, to decouple the component from the outer environment it would be better to use a one way binding `<`,

```
bindings: {
  item: '<'
}
```

this would even follow the guidelines of Angular > 1.5 that aim to a component based architecture.

From Angular 1.5 doc:

> Inputs should be using < and @ bindings. The < symbol denotes one-way
>   bindings which are available since 1.5. The difference to = is that
>   the bound properties in the component scope are not watched, which
>   means if you assign a new value to the property in the component
>   scope, it will not update the parent scope

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: It is also important that anything referencing the bound values be inside of the `this.$onInit()` function. The bound values will be undefined until the component is initialized and the $onInit has been fired. This is actually the answer to the OP's question as to why they're getting undefined. It's not because of how they're using `bindings`, though your advice is good anyway.